# Javascript loop taking too long to execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

I have been implementing an EMI calculator for a hybrid mobile application and within one of the loops the execution takes too long and ultimately the page goes unresponsive. Here is my code

```
var EMICalculator = {

basicEMI: function (amount, rate, tenure) {
    // body...
    var rate_yearly = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
    var amt = parseFloat(amount*rate_yearly*Math.pow((rate_yearly+1),tenure)/(Math.pow((rate_yearly+1),tenure)-1));
    return amt.toFixed(2);
},

getBalanceClassic: function (amount, rate, tenure, emi, openingBal, toReturn){
    var interest_per_month = 0.0;
    var schedule = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=tenure; i++){
        var dataJson = {};
        interest_per_month = amount*rate;
        amount = parseFloat(amount - emi - interest_per_month);
        dataJson['installment_no'] = i;
        dataJson['installment'] = Math.round(interest_per_month + (emi - interest_per_month)).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['interest'] = Math.round(interest_per_month).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['principal'] = Math.round(emi - interest_per_month).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['balance_principal'] = Math.round(amount).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['opening_balance'] = Math.round(openingBal).toFixed(2);
        amt_initially = Math.round(amount).toFixed(2);
        schedule.push(dataJson);
    }
    if(toReturn){
        return schedule;
    }else {
        return parseFloat(amount);
    }
},

rateBasedClassic: function (amount, rate, tenure) {
    var rate_per_yr = parseFloat((rate/12)/100); 
    var amt_initially = amount;
    var emi_basic = parseFloat(this.basicEMI(amount,rate,tenure));
    var total_interest = Math.round((emi_basic*tenure)-amount);
    var total_amount = Math.round(emi_basic*tenure);
    var interest_per_month = Math.round(total_interest/tenure);
    var amount_paid = 0.0;
    var toReturn = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=tenure; i++){
        var dataJson = {};
        amount_paid = parseFloat(amount_paid + emi_basic);
        interest_per_month = amount * rate_per_yr;
        amount = (amount - (emi_basic - interest_per_month)); 
        dataJson['installment_no'] = i;
        dataJson['installment'] = Math.round(interest_per_month + (emi_basic - interest_per_month)).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['interest'] = Math.round(interest_per_month).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['principal'] = Math.round(emi_basic - interest_per_month).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['balance_principal'] = Math.round(amount).toFixed(2);
        dataJson['opening_balance'] = Math.round(amt_initially).toFixed(2);
        amt_initially = Math.round(amount).toFixed(2);
        toReturn.push(dataJson);
    }
    return toReturn;
},

EMIBasedClassic : function (amount, tenure, emi) {
    var amt_initially = amount;
    var total_amount = emi*tenure;
    var total_interest = total_amount - amount;
    var rate = 0.0;
    var toReturn = false;
    var balance =   this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);

    while(balance<0){
        rate += 0.1;
        var rate2 = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
        balance = this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate2,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
    }

    while(balance>0){
        rate -= 0.0000001;
        var rate2 = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
        balance = this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate2,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
    } 

    toReturn = true;
    var rate2 = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
    balance = this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate2,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
    return balance;
}}
```

Calling the EMIBasedClassic method with parameters (600000,9,19080) causes the issue where the incremental increase/decrease has been done in the while loops. The same logic is working fine in Java. What's wrong here?

Comment: JavaScript is designed for web pages where locking the UI for too long (by having a long running process) causes an interrupt as your page is unresponsive.  Java doesn't give a damn.  You will want to look into background processing for this.

Comment: You need to choose some other algo for calculations or else switch to ES8 `async function` or do ajax call to java api to perform calculations on server side and return the results to client.

Answer (score 0):

When you call getBalance classic, you're using the same parameters every single time. That means balance, will always be the same value. I'm not sure which value you want to pass to the function, but the current setup will always run an infinite loop no matter what value you pass. It'd be super easy to over look such a minor thing.

```js
function (amount, tenure, emi) {
    var amt_initially = amount;
    var total_amount = emi*tenure;
    var total_interest = total_amount - amount;
    var rate = 0.0;
    var toReturn = false;
    var balance =   this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
  
    while(balance<0){
        rate += 0.1;
        var rate2 = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
        balance = this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate2,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
    }

    while(balance>0){
        console.log("__BALANCE__: ", balance);
        rate -= 0.0000001;
        var rate2 = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
        //Balance will always be the same. Do we want to pass balance or amount?
        balance = this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate2,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
    } 

    toReturn = true;
    var rate2 = parseFloat((rate/12)/100);
    balance = this.getBalanceClassic(amount,rate2,tenure,emi,amt_initially,toReturn);
    return balance;
}
```

You only want to use amount in the function on the very first time. After that, you want to use balance.
I changed it from amount to balance in the while loops and it worked.

Here's my code in repl:

[image]

Comment: Actually the issue turned out to be in the JSON object creation in every single iteration, which apparently slowed things down.. When I added the condition for creating and returning the object at the end, it stared working fine.